# WAMP server suddenly stopped running scripts

Tags: php, wamp

I have been working on a website for some months now. Every day, I open up the PHP scripts in the same manner, and every day they work just fine. Today, I go to open one up the same as I always do,  except the page just comes up as the text file. All pages are the same, I have not changed most of them for many weeks now.

WAMP is giving me no errors. I just installed the latest version, and it still won't work.

There is no problem with file extensions,

The only problem I can find is in the Apache Error Log:

```
[Fri Oct 25 10:42:40.029691 2013] [mime:warn] [pid 4860:tid 1508] AH01599: Cannot get    media type from 'x-httpd-php53'
```

What does this mean?

Answer (score 0):

That should not be x-httpd-php53. If you've just installed a new version of apache, check your configs. should be 5.3 or 5. I think in widows you need to look for httpd.conf or something like that. Sorry, me Linux!

Comment: In the httpd.conf file I have 
    AddType application/x-compress .Z
    AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz
    AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
    AddType application/x-httpd-php .php3

Comment: I changed php3 to php5.3, now the 'media type' error is gone but I've got some others which are too long to paste here, and the scripts still will not run

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this. While I had un-installed WAMP, I had not deleted the directory for the hard drive. The new install simply went over the old directory, picking up the old config files and whatever it was that caused it to stop working.

Deleting the directory and installing again fixed it.